# Order rows from lookup based on values of two fields and skip them based on priority

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Title might not be clear, sorry about that.

I'm having a little bit of trouble in solving this requirement I have.
I have a DE containing product data to show on a email templates, such like model code, color, image etc. There are also two fields in this DE named BrandNumber and ProductPriority.

Template must show 6 products, one for each brand, ordered by BrandNumber and ProductPriority;  Max value for BrandNumber can be 6, max value for ProductPriority can be anything.

Thing is, it could happen that there are not 6 brands related to a contact. For example, there could be only 5; in that case, the first two products to show will be for the highest brand number, ordered by productPriority; others will be of other BrandNumber.

[image]

Now, I'm having trouble doing this in ampscript. This is what I was doing:

```
set @contactID = _subscriberkey
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("BestProducts", 0, "BrandNumber ASC, ProductPriority ASC", "contactID", @contactID)
set @rowCount = rowCount(@rows)
var @prevBrandPriority

if @rowcount > 0 then

    set @counter = 0
    for @i = 1 to @rowcount do
        set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
        set @brandPriority = Field(@row, 'BrandPriority')

        if @brandPriority != @prevBrandPriority then

            @prevBrandPriority = @brandPriority
            
           /*set product to show */
    next @i

endif
```

But this would skip right to the next brand in any case. I've been away from coding for a while and I can't seem to come up with a solution for this, which is kinda frustrating.

Is there a way to do it without having an infinite pile of if/else statements?

Comment: Is this a transactional email or batch?

Comment: Not transactional. It will basically be a dynamic component that will be added to commercial communications in different journeys.

Comment: I'd suggest using a Query Activity to do this logic  Result would be in a sortable field in BestProducts.

Comment: Are there a fixed number of brands?  This is one of those challenges that needs to be modeled in Excel and then translated into a query.   I'd include a fake set of send source data, a fake set of BestProducts data and a mock-up the desired output.  This exercise _should_ help with a query tactic.

Comment: Once the model is done, I'd mock the same fake data in dbfiddle using a pattern like this for the related tables: https://dbfiddle.uk/AhUjEy4y.  Iterate there where you can get immediate results.

Comment: This is what I came up with, with the help of the internet. https://dpaste.org/OjHxO. It returns the right brandpriority, but product priority is always one. In order to test it, I'm putting a static number like 4 or 5 as the brandcount instead of the count. This is the result I get (brandcount at 4): https://pasteboard.co/iTSSEmFUq70M.png